# listing integers and put in array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a task that ask me to write a program to get a list of ten integers from the keyboard, put them in an array and print them off.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
   int array[10], n, numbers;

   printf("The 10 values are: \n");

   for (n = 0; n <10; n++)
   {
       printf("The values in array are: %i \n", numbers);
   }

   system("PAUSE");

   return (0);
}
```

I tried putting scanf inside the loop but it stops working after inputting the integers. Whereas in this code above, in prints out 10 of the print(s).

Comment: If you want to input ten numbers then output ten after that, then you will need two loops. Your current code has no user input at all. So there is no way to tell what the problem is. Also `numbers` is uninitialized, it will have an indeterminate value when you print it.

Comment: Please show us your code which doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand from your question I make this code, If It's not what you are looking for please explain more and give us more information.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
   int array[10], n, numbers;


   printf("The 10 values are: \n");

   for (n = 0; n <10; n++)
     {
        scanf("%d",&numbers);
        array[n] = numbers;
        printf("The values in array are: %d \n", array[n]);
     }


   system("PAUSE");

   return (0);
}
```